# Can i write from MediaRecorder to my android / linux pipe's?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I'm creating android pipe with command

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mkfifo", $"/data/user/0/ru.petrovip.proxyclient/files/videopipe").WaitForExit();`

This command make pipe `videopipe`, through application.

And open this pipe in application

`var VideoStream = System.IO.File.Open("/data/user/0/ru.petrovip.proxyclient/files/videopipe", FileMode.Open);`

Pipe is working, but i if start using `MediaRecorder` for my pipe, i catch error `Java.Lang.IllegalStateException` at `MRecorder.Prepare();`

```
MediaRecorder MRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

MRecorder.SetAudioSource(AudioSource.Mic);
MRecorder.SetVideoSource(VideoSource.Surface);
MRecorder.SetOutputFormat(OutputFormat.ThreeGpp);
MRecorder.SetOutputFile(ParcelFileDescriptor.FromFd((int)VideoStream.Handle).FileDescriptor);
MRecorder.SetVideoSize(DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels, DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels);
MRecorder.SetAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AmrNb);
MRecorder.SetVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
MRecorder.SetVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
MRecorder.SetVideoFrameRate(30);
MRecorder.Prepare();
```

Exception

```
01-18 20:23:55.471 E/MediaRecorder( 5990): prepare failed: -38
01-18 20:23:55.467 W/vip.proxyclient( 5990): type=1400 audit(0.0:876): avc: denied { read write } for path="/data/data/ru.petrovip.proxyclient/files/videopipe" dev="mmcblk0p24" ino=5435 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=fifo_file permissive=0
01-18 20:24:01.625 W/System.err( 5990): java.lang.IllegalStateException
01-18 20:24:01.627 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
01-18 20:24:01.628 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:988)
01-18 20:24:01.629 W/System.err( 5990):     at crc64c1965aae109aaff4.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
01-18 20:24:01.629 W/System.err( 5990):     at crc64c1965aae109aaff4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
01-18 20:24:01.630 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
01-18 20:24:01.631 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
01-18 20:24:01.632 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
01-18 20:24:01.633 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
01-18 20:24:01.637 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
01-18 20:24:01.638 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
01-18 20:24:01.639 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1613)
01-18 20:24:01.640 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
01-18 20:24:01.640 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
01-18 20:24:01.641 W/System.err( 5990):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
01-18 20:24:01.642 W/System.err( 5990):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-18 20:24:01.643 W/System.err( 5990):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
01-18 20:24:01.649 W/System.err( 5990):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

For other system pipe's `/dev/null` , `/dev/zero` this will work correctly, without any errors.

Is this due to security restrictions and are there other ways out of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when enabled by enabled `SELinux` status.
You need disable him by command

```
setenforce 0
```

Note: this method work only if you'r device rooted.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make MediaRecoder write into pipe on Android 2, 4, 5.1, but faced with problems:

1. Any video caused to crash:
   W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
   on Android 4, 5
   or
   E/MediaRecorder: prepare failed: -1
   on Android 2.1
2. Only audio was able to be written to pipe, but it was garbage in result, only file header was correct

So, even if SELinux would be overcome on Android 6 and higher next trouble would be MediaRecoder coudn't act with pipes possibly.